# About Laguerre's method, what is $n$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I am trying to understand Laguerre's method for finding complex roots of polynomials. I don't know what the value of $n$ should be in the equation. I have seen some people say I should always set it to $2$, however, this hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Take a look (page 667) at the marvelous book "Numerical recipes in C" (or in Fortran) available as a Google book.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is the degree of the polynomial you are trying to find the root of.  It comes in because we assume there are $n$ roots, one close and the rest an equal distance away.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre%27s_method).